# Modify NDarray for specific columns

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2d NDarray, of shape (12,8), like that:

```
[[ 89  65   4  86  44 137 113 124]
 [ 88  71   2  89  40 140 109 129]
 [ 93  71   5  87  40 139 111 129]
 [ 87  74   6  96  47 143 113 129]
 [ 81  74   3  99  47 144 112 129]
 [ 86  64   4  89  47 139 115 123]
 [ 85  76   1  93  38 142 106 132]
 [ 89  80   4  94  38 143 107 134]
 [ 84  68   4  93  48 141 114 125]
 [ 95  42  14  80  65 130 135 107]
 [ 90  35   1  67  50 124 123 104]
 [ 68  36   1  84  63 129 126  97]]
```

I need to apply a simple function `val = 200 - val` to all odd-numbered columns. How could I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do smth like this:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.arange(49).reshape(7, 7)
print(arr)
arr[:, 1::2] = 200 - arr[:, 1::2]
print(arr)
```

output:

```
[[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6]
 [ 7  8  9 10 11 12 13]
 [14 15 16 17 18 19 20]
 [21 22 23 24 25 26 27]
 [28 29 30 31 32 33 34]
 [35 36 37 38 39 40 41]
 [42 43 44 45 46 47 48]]
[[  0 199   2 197   4 195   6]
 [  7 192   9 190  11 188  13]
 [ 14 185  16 183  18 181  20]
 [ 21 178  23 176  25 174  27]
 [ 28 171  30 169  32 167  34]
 [ 35 164  37 162  39 160  41]
 [ 42 157  44 155  46 153  48]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply by taking odd numbers as your indices:

```
>>> a = np.asarray([[ 89,  65,   4,  86,  44, 137, 113, 124],
                    [ 88,  71,   2,  89,  40, 140, 109, 129],
                    [ 93,  71,   5,  87,  40, 139, 111, 129],
                    [ 87,  74,   6,  96,  47, 143, 113, 129],
                    [ 81,  74,   3,  99,  47, 144, 112, 129],
                    [ 86,  64,   4,  89,  47, 139, 115, 123],
                    [ 85,  76,   1,  93,  38, 142, 106, 132],
                    [ 89,  80,   4,  94,  38, 143, 107, 134],
                    [ 84,  68,   4,  93,  48, 141, 114, 125],
                    [ 95,  42,  14,  80,  65, 130, 135, 107],
                    [ 90,  35,   1,  67,  50, 124, 123, 104],
                    [ 68,  36,   1,  84,  63, 129, 126,  97]])

>>> idx = np.arange(1,a.shape[1] + 1, 2) #odd-numbered indices
>>> a[:, idx] = 200 - a[:, idx]

>>> a

array([[ 89, 135,   4, 114,  44,  63, 113,  76],
       [ 88, 129,   2, 111,  40,  60, 109,  71],
       [ 93, 129,   5, 113,  40,  61, 111,  71],
       [ 87, 126,   6, 104,  47,  57, 113,  71],
       [ 81, 126,   3, 101,  47,  56, 112,  71],
       [ 86, 136,   4, 111,  47,  61, 115,  77],
       [ 85, 124,   1, 107,  38,  58, 106,  68],
       [ 89, 120,   4, 106,  38,  57, 107,  66],
       [ 84, 132,   4, 107,  48,  59, 114,  75],
       [ 95, 158,  14, 120,  65,  70, 135,  93],
       [ 90, 165,   1, 133,  50,  76, 123,  96],
       [ 68, 164,   1, 116,  63,  71, 126, 103]])
```